# Having an eye on what site visitor are doing?

Tags: php, logging

Lets say I have a website, hosted with a hosting company with limited reach for log files (access, error) files for both php & apache.

But still want to know what URLs/queries are accessed or submitted to my site and specially to my database through the GET & POST?

I have a main file witch is included in all other pages on my site, can I turn that file to a simple PHP script that can capture requested data through POST & GET?

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) for this purpose. It will be able to tell you everything that is going on in your site.

You could also use the Server global

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

to access the query string on every page and store that in a database or more likely in a log text file.

So in your file that you are including on every page you can add this to your log file:

record the date:

```
time(); // will give you the number of seconds from the Unix Epoch. This can then be translated back into a readable format with the date() function.
```

record the ip:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Records the IP address of the client requesting the page.
```

record the URL:

```
 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // will give you the full url entered.
```

Post data will be very hard to record all submissions without going into the code and recording it where it shows up.

Comment: If we forget the POST data for now, How would you implement the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to log the date,ip, browser and full URL to a text file?

Comment: @JohanLarsson see my update answer. Note that Google Analtics is the best answer to this question

Comment: What I basically need is a replacement for Apache access & error log files. I can't access those files and want to have a replacement where I can see the served or not served requests (Both good and bad requests). Google Analytics keeps tracks of the served requests only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) for some seriously detailed stats on how users interact with your site. It's free and provides great info. All you need to do is include a piece of javascript on every page you want to track (Easy to do with an included PHP file)

Comment: Original poster mentioned POST and sql queries.  Google Analytics can't track POST requests as the parameters wouldn't be logged.  The only choice is to add some logging code to the PHP.  The question is where to put it.  One could log to the database or to the file system, but this additional logging will have some performance penalty.

Comment: He could use the async database queries

Comment: I have already done that, but id doesn't capture the 404,403 requests?! in other words it does capture the accessed URL and NOT the error ones.